# Javascript works in JS Fiddle but doesn't work in Chrome/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I cannot understand why my code doesn't work in my browsers but it works in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4tafnwcj/2/

When I click on a plan, the total should output the price, however, this doesn't happen in the browser. I have checked dev tools, cleared cache, but it didn't help. I also have included all the neccessary jquery,js files, but it seems like there is something else breaking it. I don't know why. Please, help and explain what is the issue.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_SCRIPT?>jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_SCRIPT?>jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_SCRIPT?>jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_SCRIPT?>bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_SCRIPT?>icheck.min.js"></script>
```

code:

```
<div class="checkout">
                        <span id="checkout-title">Checkout</span>
                        <div class="plan-wrapper">
                        <label id="silver-plan"><input class="btn-checkbox-plan" type="radio" name="groupnine" value="699" onclick="calculate(this);"/>Cyber Security Silver Plan</label>
                        <label id="silver-plan-price">$699</label>
                        <label id="gold-plan"><input class="btn-checkbox-plan" type="radio" name="groupnine" value="999" onclick="calculate(this);"/>Cyber Security Gold Plan</label>
                        <label id="gold-plan-price">$999</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <span id="personalized-logo">Personalized Logo</span>
                            <span id="logo-price">$49.99</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tax-wrapper">
                            <div class="wrapper-a">
                            <span id="tax">Tax + Processing</span>
                            <span id="tax-price">$0.00</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="total-wrapper">
                            <div class="wrapper-b">
                            <span id="total">Total</span>
                            <output type="number" name="price" id="output"></output>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls submit-btn">
                            <input  type="submit" value="Checkout" />
                            <input  type="reset" value="Clear" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls back-btn">
                            <input  class="back-button" type="button" value="Back" />
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/.checkout -->
```

.js

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-checkbox-plan", function(e){
     //alert();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){

        $("#output").html($(this).val());
     }

   });  

});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any error message in the console log?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me and shows  `Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined`

Comment: not at all, there are no errors

Comment: Even when you provide a link to a fiddle, the relevant code must be **in** your question, not just linked.

Comment: @cherry_red: With the fiddle? Yes there are, more than one in fact. Open your web console, you'll see what popovitsj is talking about.

Comment: Here's a partially-fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3tdwak2h/1/ But you still haven't put the `calculate` function in it.

Comment: double check my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4tafnwcj/2/

Comment: @T.J. Crowder my console doesn't give any error messages

Comment: @cherry_red: Click one of your radio buttons. You're referencing a function, `calculate`, that doesn't exist. I can see it in your HTML, and it's not defined in the JavaScript. Just go look. popovitsj and I have no reason to tell you this if it isn't true.

Comment: I get the same error using Firebug in Mozilla: `ReferenceError: calculate is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the onclick="calculate(this);" as I don't need it, I don't have anything to calculate.

http://jsfiddle.net/3tdwak2h/4/ in fiddle my code runs, however, not in my browser. And in the Chrome console log the only error I get is  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

code

```
<div class="checkout">
                        <span id="checkout-title">Checkout</span>
                        <div class="plan-wrapper">
                        <label id="silver-plan"><input class="btn-checkbox-plan" type="radio" name="groupnine" value="699" /> Silver Plan</label>
                        <label id="silver-plan-price">$699</label>
                        <label id="gold-plan"><input class="btn-checkbox-plan" type="radio" name="groupnine" value="999" /> Gold Plan</label>
                        <label id="gold-plan-price">$999</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <span id="personalized-logo">Personalized Logo</span>
                            <span id="logo-price">$49.99</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tax-wrapper">
                            <div class="wrapper-a">
                            <span id="tax">Tax + Processing</span>
                            <span id="tax-price">$0.00</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="total-wrapper">
                            <div class="wrapper-b">
                            <span id="total">Total</span>
                            <output type="number" name="price" id="output"></output>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls submit-btn">
                            <input  type="submit" value="Checkout" />
                            <input  type="reset" value="Clear" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls back-btn">
                            <input  class="back-button" type="button" value="Back" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

.js

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     //alert();
   $(document).on("click", ".btn-checkbox-plan", function(e){
     if($(".btn-checkbox-plan").is(':checked')){

    $("#output").html($(this).val());
}

   });  

 });
```